# AuthenticationForm.is_valid() always return False

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django.
form.is_valid() always return False.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class SignInForm(AuthenticationForm):
    pass
```

View(accounts:create) is below.

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
                form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
                form.cleaned_data.get('email'),
                form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:thanks'))
    else:
        form = CreateForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/create.html', {'form': form})
```

Custom user model is below.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Test method is below.

```
response = self.client.post(reverse('accounts:create'),
                         {
                             'username': 'user2',
                             'email': 'user2@kexi.jp',
                             'password1': 'example2',
                             'password2': 'example2',
                         })
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
form = SignInForm({'username': 'user2', 'password': 'example2'})
self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

form.is_valid() always return False.
Why???

Comment: Try to print `form.errors`

Comment: Can you show the setup for the test where you create the user?

Comment: How did you create a user for the given password?

Comment: Can you share the logic of the `accounts:create` view?

Comment: len(form.errors) == 0

Comment: In your view, when you call `create_user`, you pass the password as `form.cleaned_data.get('password')` but the fields are named `password1` and `password2`, is this passing `None` as the password because that key doesn't exist in cleaned_data?

Comment: If you print `CustomUser.objects.values()` do you get your user with `is_active=True` and a `password`?

Comment: fixed from 'password' to 'password1'

Comment: Thank your comments guys. I confirmed is_active = True.

Comment: still returns False..

Comment: authenticate(username='user2',password='example2') is not None.

Answer (score 0):

Changed from

```
SignInForm(request.POST)
```

to

```
SignInForm(data=request.POST)
```

It works.